# Get pixel(Row Column) from Lat Long for Moon

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff, ogr, moon

How to obtain pixel(Row Column) Value from Latitude and Longitude given, for Moon?

Actually, I am Having a GeoTiff file which contains craters, and I need to crop the specific Crater whose Center is given to me in the form of Latitude and longitude.

I know that I have to use gdal to get this done, but I am having wrong results from my code.

Code is in Python
Code:

```
from osgeo import osr, gdal
import sys

# get the existing coordinate system
#SPHEROID["MOON_localRadius",1737400,0]
# create the new coordinate system
ds = gdal.Open("C:\Users\ZARL\Desktop\PRL_Project\small.tif")
old_cs= osr.SpatialReference()
old_cs.ImportFromWkt(ds.GetProjectionRef())
wgs84_wkt = """
        GEOGCS["GCS_MOON",
    DATUM["D_MOON",
        SPHEROID["MOON_localRadius",1737400,0]],
    PRIMEM["Reference_Meridian",0],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
PROJECTION["Equirectangular"],
PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],
PARAMETER["central_meridian",22.46049118041992],
PARAMETER["standard_parallel_1",0],
PARAMETER["false_easting",0],
PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
UNIT["metre",1,
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]]]"""
new_cs = osr.SpatialReference()
new_cs .ImportFromWkt(wgs84_wkt)

# create a transform object to convert between coordinate systems
transform = osr.CoordinateTransformation(old_cs,new_cs) 

#get the point to transform, pixel (0,0) in this case
width = ds.RasterXSize
height = ds.RasterYSize
gt = ds.GetGeoTransform()
minx = gt[0]
miny = gt[3] + width*gt[4] + height*gt[5] 

#get the coordinates in lat long
#latlong = transform.TransformPoint(minx,miny) 



transform1 = ds.GetGeoTransform()

xOrigin = transform1[0]
yOrigin = transform1[3]
pixelWidth = transform1[1]
pixelHeight = -transform1[5]

latlong = transform.TransformPoint(xOrigin,yOrigin)
#data = band.ReadAsArray(0, 0, width, height)

points_list = [ (22.4655,-71.7136)] #list of Lat long

for point in points_list:
    col = int((point[0] - latlong[1]) / pixelWidth)
    row = int((latlong[0]-point[1] ) / pixelHeight)


    print row,col
```

I am getting wrong values.

The Tiff file is:https://www.dropbox.com/s/twov5jpe40hcf4q/small.tif?dl=0

[image: This is a Tiff file in which Lat Long and other info is tagged]

when I run gdalinfo command on the picture I get the following:

```
    Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: small.tif
       small.tif.aux.xml
Size is 40, 33
Coordinate System is:
PROJCS["unnamed",
    GEOGCS["GCS_MOON",
        DATUM["D_MOON",
            SPHEROID["MOON_localRadius",1737400,0]],
        PRIMEM["Reference_Meridian",0],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    PROJECTION["Equirectangular"],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",22.46049118041992],
    PARAMETER["standard_parallel_1",0],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",0],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]]]
Origin = (135.724395353784870,-2174581.951404873300000)
Pixel Size = (0.812720930262190,-0.812720930262190)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
  TIFFTAG_XRESOLUTION=1
  TIFFTAG_YRESOLUTION=1
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (     135.724,-2174581.951) ( 22d27'53.88"E, 71d42'47.22"S)
Lower Left  (     135.724,-2174608.771) ( 22d27'53.88"E, 71d42'50.40"S)
Upper Right (     168.233,-2174581.951) ( 22d27'57.74"E, 71d42'47.22"S)
Lower Right (     168.233,-2174608.771) ( 22d27'57.74"E, 71d42'50.40"S)
Center      (     151.979,-2174595.361) ( 22d27'55.81"E, 71d42'48.81"S)
Band 1 Block=40x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Gray
  Min=1.000 Max=254.000
  Minimum=1.000, Maximum=254.000, Mean=122.977, StdDev=48.776
  Metadata:
    STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=254
    STATISTICS_MEAN=122.97651515152
    STATISTICS_MINIMUM=1
    STATISTICS_STDDEV=48.776222721807
```

Any Other Approach is also fine.

Comment: Is the WKT working at all? It should start out "PROJCS["name",GEOGCS{]..."

Comment: That "Tiff" is a PNG and without the original Tiff we can't get the metadata that it might contain. For example, we need to know the corner coordinates of the image, which are normally obtained from GeoTIFF metadata.

Comment: I have updated the question

Answer (score 2):

I have done the solution and it is working for almost every cases. I am putting the solution over here. It is done in python.

Code:

```
from osgeo import osr,gdal

infile = "C:\Users\ZARL\Desktop\PRL_Project\gale463m.tif" #File Path goes here
#Lat Long value
long = 137.855486
lat =  -5.378912

indataset = gdal.Open( infile)

srs = osr.SpatialReference()
srs.ImportFromWkt(indataset.GetProjection())

srsLatLong = srs.CloneGeogCS()
ct = osr.CoordinateTransformation(srsLatLong, srs)
(X, Y, height) = ct.TransformPoint(long, lat)

# Report results
print('longitude: %f\t\tlatitude: %f' % (long, lat))
print('X: %f\t\tY: %f' % (X, Y))
#VALUE OF COORDINATE IN METERS
print X ,Y

driver = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff')
band = indataset.GetRasterBand(1)

cols = indataset.RasterXSize
rows = indataset.RasterYSize

transform = indataset.GetGeoTransform()

xOrigin = transform[0]
yOrigin = transform[3]
pixelWidth = transform[1]
pixelHeight = -transform[5]
data = band.ReadAsArray(0, 0, cols, rows)

points_list = [(X,Y)] #list of X,Y coordinates

for point in points_list:
    col = int((point[0] - xOrigin) / pixelWidth )
    row = int((yOrigin - point[1] ) / pixelHeight)
    #ROW AND COLUMN VALUE
    print row,col
    #Data AT THAT ROW COLUMN
    value = data[row][col]

    print value
```

This will give the data value at that pixel whose Lat Long is provided.

Comment: @Sai kiran this code is for one pair of Lat long. Now if you want to do same task for multiples pairs of Lat Long just put this code snippet in the loop and iterate through every pair. Time complexity won't be the issue it will be linear to number of queries. I did that for more than 2L data points and it did compute the results successfully!